# How to query entity by generated ID

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

## The case

I'm kinda new to Google Cloud Datastore and am learning from their docs and tests under NodeJS.

```
datastore.save([ entity ], (error, apiResponse) =>
{
    console.log('---', key);
    console.log('---', error);
    console.log('---', apiResponse);
    datastore.get(key).then(([entity]) =>
    {
        console.log('+++', entity);
        console.log('+++', entity[DatastoreClient.KEY] === key);

        let query = datastore.createQuery(kind).filter('__key__', '=', datastore.key(kind));

        datastore.runQuery(query).then(([entity]) =>
        {
            console.log('...', entity);
        }).catch(console.log).then(() =>
        {
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

The saved entity output in the console is similar to

```
{
    a: 'Aa',
    z: 'Zz',
    [Symbol(KEY)]: Key {
        namespace: undefined,
        id: '30',
        kind: 'mch-gw/healthz/jgtdjd6h',
        path: [Getter]
    }
}
```

## The issue

It also happens that few lines down, when I run the query, I get

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Key path element must not be incomplete: [mch-gw/healthz/jgtdjd6h: ]
```

I do understand that my key don't have to be incomplete, but how to avoid ?

## What's the original purpose ?

As you can see the above output for saved entoty, there is an `id` field which value is `'30'`.

I want to be able to search by that `id` generated value.

**Thanks to all in advance !!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for even query, since `kind` and `id` are known

```
datastore.save([ entity ], (error, apiResponse) =>
{
    console.log('---', key);
    console.log('---', key.path);
    console.log('---', error);
    console.log('---', apiResponse);

    const id = apiResponse[0].mutationResults[0].key.path[0].id;
    // note however, that if the entity is to be updated: ie it already have
    // entity[DatastoreClient.KEY] as a complete key, then
    // null === apiResponse[0].mutationResults[0].key;

    // also note that this `id` value need to be parsed as int...
    // since it is auto-generated by google-cloud-storage engine
    // and YES, even though output of entity seems to show it as a string
    // it costed me 06h testing à vue, stumbling and messing in order to figure it out, so beware
    const _key = datastore.key([kind, +id]);
    datastore.get(_key).then(([entity]) =>
    {
        console.log('+++', entity);
    }, console.log).then(done);
});
```

And the fetch output is as expected

```
{
    a: 'Aa',
    z: 'Zz',
    [Symbol(KEY)]: Key {
        namespace: undefined,
        id: '42',
        kind: 'mch-gw/healthz/jgtdjd6h',
        path: [Getter]
    }
}
```